# How can I do lots of frontflips?

Tags: trials-frontier

I was given the challenge to do 25 backflips and 25 frontflips in 60 minutes.  I found out that on a steep hill, I can do a backflip and land on the incline, so I have all 25 backflips from one level.

As for frontflips, is there a level that is best for getting a lot of frontflips on?  Is there some way to get them all in one spot?

Answer (score 1):

The last jump in dust bowl before the goal can be repeated for easy front flips. It should only take 4 or 5 minutes to get 25 front flips using this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have unlocked The Trebuchet then you can do many frontflips at the part which is close to the finish line. The place which is made up of skeletons. The frontflips can be achieved by going back and sprinting forward repeatedly.